# Navigated React Native component is not rendered properly after updating its parent's state

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have a parent component with Navigator and 2 child components.
In parent component I have a method that updates the height of a View it has, which I pass to child components, allowing them to refresh the state of the parent once they are mounted.

When I navigate directly to second child, then call this method in second child's componentDidMount, the second child is re-rendered properly.
However, when I navigate from first child to second, the second child is not re-rendered as expected.

Parent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import FirstChild from './FirstChild';
import SecondChild from './SecondChild';

export default class Parent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setViewHeight = this.setViewHeight.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      viewHeight : 200
    }
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {

     var child = route.name == 'FirstChild' ?
      <FirstChild navigator={navigator} heightSetter={this.setViewHeight}/> :
      <SecondChild navigator={navigator} heightSetter={this.setViewHeight}/>;

     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <View style={[styles.dynamicView, {height: this.state.viewHeight}]}/>
         {child}
       </View>
    )    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        ref='navigator'
        initialRoute={{ name: 'FirstChild' }}
        renderScene={(route,navigator)=>this.renderScene(route,navigator)}
      />
    );
  }

  setViewHeight() {
    this.setState({
      viewHeight: 100
    })
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  dynamicView: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(100,100,200, 0.5)'
  }
});
```

First Child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export default class FirstChild extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child} onPress={() => this.props.navigator.push({name: 'SecondChild'}) }>
        <View style={styles.child}>
          <Text>FIRST</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  child: {
    height: 200,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200,100,100,0.5)'
  }
});
```

Second Child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class SecondChild extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.heightSetter();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.child}>
        <Text>Second</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  child: {
    height: 200,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200,100,100,0.5)'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The question you are putting is not clear actually. What is the behavior that you got? Without clear picture of that it's not possible to answer your question but can tell you one thing that is

Using the navigation which is built in to react native is little complex and when there are many scenes to go through it doesn't support at all.

You can use navigation library like react-native router flux, which will definitely help you solve the issue you have got.

Here is the link,

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: Thanks, I will check this component. What I want to do eventually is to let each component decides if it wants to have navigation bar or not, this is just a sample code to demonstrate the problem. In this sample, I would expect that SecondChild will be "pull up", since it is updating the height of the parent's sub view from 200 to 100, however it remains in the same position as if the sub view height is still 200.

Comment: You can hide the navbar in this as hidenavbar={true/false}. If my answer was helpful in anyway could you please upvote my answer. :D

Comment: You mean in react-native-router-flux or in built in navigation ? if you're talking about react-native-router-flux I will have to give it a chance and integrate it first to replace the build it navigation. Meanwhile I found a workaround for the built in navigation so I'll stay with it.

Comment: I will suggest you to leave the inbuilt navigation, it really gets into trouble when you have to go to and fro around some view. Implementation of react-native router flux is far easy. Once you have got the understanding of how the navigation works its wise to migrate IMO .Cheers